# Set React Context inside function-only component

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-context

My goal is very simple. I am just looking to set my react context from within a reusable function-only (stateless?) react component.

When this reusable function gets called it will set the context (state inside) to values i provide. The problem is of course you can't import react inside a function-only component and hence I cannot set the context throughout my app.

There's nothing really to show its a simple problem.

But just in case:

```
<button onCLick={() => PlaySong()}></button>

export function PlaySong() {
  const {currentSong, setCurrentSong} = useContext(StoreContext) //cannot call useContext in this component
}
```

If i use a regular react component, i cannot call this function onClick:

```
export default function PlaySong() {
  const {currentSong, setCurrentSong} = useContext(StoreContext) //fine
}
```

But:

```
<button onCLick={() => <PlaySong />}></button> //not an executable function
```

One solution: I know i can easily solve this problem by simply creating a Playbtn component and place that in every song so it plays the song. The problem with this approach is that i am using a react-player library so i cannot place a Playbtn component in there...

Comment: Are you using `<button onCLick={() => <PlaySong />}>` from within React component?

Comment: If you're looking for a mechanism to use React hooks within a function, add some extra functionality to it and then use that within React component - take a look at the [Custom Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html). You can use them in your example with play button as well.

Comment: but i dont need custom hooks i need to set the context state only

Comment: You can only use hooks from other hooks or react components.

Comment: im aware of that. So i dont have a solution now...

Comment: why do you want to call use context in a "onclickable" method? 
You can call useContextHooks  like your first example and then wrote a "onclickable"  function where you call  setCurrenSong() or current song (depends on what you want to do)

Answer (score 1):

You're so close!  You just need to define the callback *inside* the function component.

```
export const PlaySongButton = ({...props}) => {
  
  const {setCurrentSong} = useContext(StoreContext);

  const playSong = () => {
    setCurrentSong("some song");
  }

  return (
    <button 
      {...props}
      onClick={() => playSong()}
    />
  )
}
```

If you want greater re-usability, you can create custom hooks to consume your context.  Of course where you use these still has to follow the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

```
export const useSetCurrentSong = (song) => {
  const {setCurrentSong} = useContext(StoreContext);
  setCurrentSong(song);
}
```

It is possible to trigger a hook function by *rendering* a component, but you cannot *call* a component like you are trying to do.

```
const PlaySong = () => {
  const {setCurrentSong} = useContext(StoreContext);
  useEffect( () => { 
     setCurrentSong("some song");
    }, []
  }
  return null;
}
```

```
const MyComponent = () => {
   const [shouldPlay, setShouldPlay] = useState(false);
   
   return (
     <>
       <button onClick={() => setShouldPlay(true)}>Play</button>
       {shouldPlay && <PlaySong />}
     </>
   ) 
}
```